# Subgradient of the optimal value of a linear program with respect to its parameters

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider the linear program $f(c)=\min\{c'x\mid x\in\mathbb{R}^n,Ax=b,x\geq0\}$. Are there any results on what is $\partial f/\partial b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered by the sensitivity interpretation of the Lagrange multipliers.  (Linear programming books or convex optimization books should discuss the sensitivity interpretation.)  If $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier for the constraint $Ax = b$, then $-\lambda$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $b$.